# wp_list_comments function not working in wordpress 4.3.16 version

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am adding load more comments button in comments section. i want load function wp_list_comments using Ajax, function are loading but wp_list_comment not display in wordpress 4.3.16 version. How to solve this problem???
My code are is:

// maybe it isn't the best way to declare global $post variable, but it is simple and works perfectly!

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cloadmore', 'misha_comments_loadmore_handler'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cloadmore', 'misha_comments_loadmore_handler'); 

function misha_comments_loadmore_handler(){

    global $post;
    $post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // actually we must copy the params from wp_list_comments() used in our theme
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'page' => $_POST['cpage'], // current comment page
        'per_page' => get_option('comments_per_page'),
        'style' => '<div>', // comments won't wrapped in this tag and it is awesome!
        'short_ping' => true,

    ) );

    die; // don't forget this thing if you don't want "0" to be displayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cloadmore', 'misha_comments_loadmore_handler'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cloadmore', 'misha_comments_loadmore_handler'); 

function misha_comments_loadmore_handler(){

    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => $_POST['post_id'],
        'status' => 'approve' 
    ));


    wp_list_comments(array(
        'page' => $_POST['cpage'], // current comment page
        'per_page' => get_option('comments_per_page'),
        'style' => '<div>', // comments won't wrapped in this tag and it is awesome!
        'short_ping' => true,
    ), $comments);

    die; // don't forget this thing if you don't want "0" to be displayed
}
```